# Terminal stops printing while it is supposed to be printing continually with a python loop

Tags: python, linux, bash, terminal, ubuntu-14.04

I have written a python script to automatically check internet available and login in with my student account as well as restart ngrok when finding losing connection with internet. I run these scripts on my laptop installed with Ubuntu 14.04.

The python script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import os
import urllib
import http
from urllib.request import urlopen
import http.cookiejar
import time
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse


def is_online():
    """check net available"""
    pattern = "location.href='http://210.77.16.21:80"
    with urlopen('http://www.baidu.com') as fh:
        data = fh.read().decode()
    if len(data) < 500 or pattern in data:
        return False
    else:
        return True

def login(user, password):
    login_url = 'http://210.77.16.21/eportal/InterFace.do?method=login'
    login_data = {
        'userId': user,
        'password': password,
        'service': '',
        'queryString': 'wlanuserip=0bc386d9e643d188b011a0d00c9b5c40&wlanacname=5fcbc245a7ffdfa4&ssid=&nasip=2c0716b583c8ac3cbd7567a84cfde5a8&mac=53ba540bde596b811a6d5617a86fa028&t=wireless-v2&url=2c0328164651e2b4f13b933ddf36628bea622dedcc302b30',
        'operatorPwd': '',
        'validcode': ''
    }
    login_data = urllib.parse.urlencode(login_data)
    cookie = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
    cookie_support = urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie)
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener(cookie_support, urllib.request.HTTPHandler)
    urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
    request = urllib.request.Request(url=login_url, data=login_data.encode())
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    html = response.read().decode()
    logined = True
    if "success" in html:
        pass
    else:
        logined = False
    return logined

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        print (time.strftime('%l:%M%p %Z on %b %d, %Y'))
        if is_online():
            print ("++++++++++ you have already been online ++++++++++\n")
        else:
            print ("---------- you have lost net connection ----------\n")
            os.system('sudo hclient -r -v eth0')
            os.system('sudo dhclient -v eth0')
            login('username', 'password')
            os.system('./ngrok.sh')
        time.sleep(20)
```

And the bash script called by python script shows below:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo killall sunny
gnome-terminal -x bash -c './sunny clientid de70fb9da4504ca2,4b7359b627c409a5,925860be03fffe58'
```

When run `python3 ./net.py` in terminal, it is supposed to be printing info continually every 20 seconds.

However, the wired thing is that terminal will stop printing after a while and get stuck here:

```
12:17AM CST on Aug 06, 2017
++++++++++ you have already been online ++++++++++
12:18AM CST on Aug 06, 2017
++++++++++ you have already been online ++++++++++
12:18AM CST on Aug 06, 2017
++++++++++ you have already been online ++++++++++
12:18AM CST on Aug 06, 2017
++++++++++ you have already been online ++++++++++
12:19AM CST on Aug 06, 2017
++++++++++ you have already been online ++++++++++
12:19AM CST on Aug 06, 2017
```

It seems like the error occurs after the line `print (time.strftime('%l:%M%p %Z on %b %d, %Y'))`.

I have tested it twice and the first time it got stuck after running approximately 12 hours while the second time it got stuck in less than 20 minutes.

I also checked the python script status using command `pa -aux |grep python3`, it shows like this:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
keshawn  26339  0.0  0.1  59360 15656 pts/0    S+   00:00   0:00 python3 ./net.py
```

So, can anyone figure out why this strange phenomenon happens?

Comment: You could perhaps add a timeout to `urlopen()` as it may hang.

Comment: In particular, evil university wifi often causes routing issues that manifest as hangs.

Comment: @Gribouillis Thanks, it works. And I have push the full scripts on [github](https://github.com/keshawnhsieh/nas), hoping it can give a reference for those who later encounter this problem.